# вместо post работает get

Tags: php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    echo "МОё имя, ".$_POST['name'];
}



?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#" mathod="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
    <input type="submit" value="отправить" >
    


</form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что у вас опечатка, нужно написать `method` вместо `mathod` в теге `form`, тогда всё заработает, вот правильный вариант:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    echo "МОё имя, ".$_POST['name'];
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
    <input type="submit" value="отправить" >
</form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в написании атрибута тега "Form". Стоит заменить "mathod" на "method".

```
<form action="#" mathod="post">
```

заменить на:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
```